# I have a .exe program file compiled using Intel Fortran 8.1. for windows 10. Can I edit the code off the .exe file?

Tags: file-format, executable

I have a .exe program file compiled using Intel Fortran 8.1 for Windows under WinXP with 64-bit Windows 10 system.

Can I edit the code off the .exe file? I need to change a value in the code.

Thank you!

Comment: Possibly, if you can find it in the binary. This will be easier if e.g. it's the only instance of that value in the calculation, and hasn't been merged with other values at compile time. But it's going to be a lot simpler and safer to just modify the source and recompile with the new value. If you don't have the source yourself your first step should be to talk to the people who do.

Comment: Could you post some more details or upload the executable you want to patch?